# How to update persistent app in android P

Tags: android

Our App is a system app,for app live, we use `android:persistent="true"` in manifest,but the update failed.

Here is the error message:

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package com.skyroam.silverhelper
>   is a persistent app. Persistent apps are not updateable.]

How can i update persistent app in android P?

Answer (score 0):

1. copy the app and permissions (if modified) to your compute.
2. update the app on device and reboot. Follow below steps

```html
adb root
adb disable-verity
adb reboot
adb root
adb remount
adb push .\privapp-permissions-com.SystemControler.xml /etc/permissions/
adb push .\SystemControler.apk /system/priv-app/SystemControler/
adb shell
su
cd /system/priv-app/SystemControler/
chmod 644 SystemControler.apk
reboot
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You can put on  tag in AndriodManifest.xml

```
   android:persistent="false"
```

or remove

```
   android:persistent="true"
```

for android:persistent default value is false

Comment: this is wrong,  android:persistent mean's keep app in memory, has nothing to do with persistent app in /system